# Ubuntu 18.04 almost every web browser isn't working except firefox

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, chromium, crash, opera

I have tried installing Chrome, Chromium, Brave, Opera and they all crash after a few secs. I have no idea what's causing this. The only web browser that still works for me is FireFox. Any help would be appreciated.

System info:

```
$vmstat; lscpu
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0 19329548 144508 9784220    0    0    57   198  128  400  3  1 96  0  0
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              12
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-11
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  6
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               158
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz
Stepping:            10
CPU MHz:             4112.579
CPU max MHz:         4600.0000
CPU min MHz:         800.0000
BogoMIPS:            6399.96
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            12288K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-11
```

and

```
$uname -a
Linux P7xxTM1 5.3.0-26-generic #28~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 18 16:40:14 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm running out of web browsers here lol

side note: I used terminal/apt to install the browsers for chrome/chromium and i downloaded opera off the website than opened it with software store install instead of snap.

edit:

Here's what the output in terminal when I launch Chrome from it.

```
$sensible-browser
[24166:1:0118/165230.672121:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[24166:1:0118/165230.672495:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[24166:1:0118/165230.738183:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[24166:1:0118/165230.738403:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[24166:1:0118/165230.738755:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[24166:1:0118/165230.739024:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
../../sandbox/linux/seccomp-bpf-helpers/sigsys_handlers.cc:**CRASHING**:(tg)kill() failure
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
../../sandbox/linux/seccomp-bpf-helpers/sigsys_handlers.cc:**CRASHING**:(tg)kill() failure
--2020-01-18 16:52:49--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 172.217.0.14, 2607:f8b0:4009:813::200e
Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|172.217.0.14|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘/dev/fd/4’

Crash dump id: 6783467315c400cc
     0K
                                                        2.59M=0s

2020-01-18 16:52:50 (2.59 MB/s) - ‘/dev/fd/4’ saved [16]

[25221:7:0118/165250.548475:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(124)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuChannelMsg_CreateCommandBuffer.
[25221:1:0118/165250.868397:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[25221:1:0118/165250.868820:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[25221:1:0118/165250.869817:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[25221:1:0118/165250.870163:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[25221:1:0118/165250.870622:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[25221:1:0118/165250.870915:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[25221:1:0118/165250.871470:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[25221:1:0118/165250.871735:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
../../sandbox/linux/seccomp-bpf-helpers/sigsys_handlers.cc:**CRASHING**:(tg)kill() failure
--2020-01-18 16:52:59--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 172.217.0.14, 2607:f8b0:4009:813::200e
Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|172.217.0.14|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... [25328:7:0118/165259.240123:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(124)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuChannelMsg_CreateCommandBuffer.
[25221:7:0118/165259.240777:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(124)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuChannelMsg_CreateCommandBuffer.
200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘/dev/fd/4’

     0K             
  Crash dump id:   c12b7c917021e48c 
                                      2.35M=0s

[25433:1:0118/165303.771155:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[25433:1:0118/165303.771502:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[25433:1:0118/165303.772068:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[25433:1:0118/165303.772523:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[25438:1:0118/165304.026215:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[25438:1:0118/165304.027485:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[25434:1:0118/165308.443739:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[25434:1:0118/165308.444426:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
../../sandbox/linux/seccomp-bpf-helpers/sigsys_handlers.cc:**CRASHING**:(tg)kill() failure
--2020-01-18 16:53:10--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 172.217.0.14, 2607:f8b0:4009:813::200e
Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|172.217.0.14|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘/dev/fd/4’

     0K                   
   Crash dump id:   ebec1ff14e62c0d1 
                               2.70M=0s

2020-01-18 16:53:10 (2.70 MB/s) - ‘/dev/fd/4’ saved [16]

../../sandbox/linux/seccomp-bpf-helpers/sigsys_handlers.cc:**CRASHING**:(tg)kill() failure
--2020-01-18 16:53:24--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 172.217.0.14, 2607:f8b0:4009:813::200e
Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|172.217.0.14|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘/dev/fd/4’

     0K              
  Crash dump id:  88d5a8d484ada05a 
                                      2.37M=0s

[25544:1:0118/165329.735896:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[25544:1:0118/165329.736356:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[25544:1:0118/165331.204150:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[25544:1:0118/165331.204486:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
../../sandbox/linux/seccomp-bpf-helpers/sigsys_handlers.cc:**CRASHING**:(tg)kill() failure
--2020-01-18 16:53:34--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 172.217.0.14, 2607:f8b0:4009:813::200e
Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|172.217.0.14|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... [26258:26258:0118/165334.467766:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(450)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: Failed to create shared context for virtualization.
200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘/dev/fd/4’

     0K                    
 Crash dump id:  51ef3913492d0890 
                                 2.76M=0s

../../sandbox/linux/seccomp-bpf-helpers/sigsys_handlers.cc:**CRASHING**:(tg)kill() failure
--2020-01-18 16:53:44--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 172.217.0.14, 2607:f8b0:4009:813::200e
Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|172.217.0.14|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... [26344:26344:0118/165344.708145:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(450)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: Failed to create shared context for virtualization.
200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘/dev/fd/4’


     0KCrash dump id:  10e6e1b94c812a11  
                                           [24152:24159:0118/165349.344724:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(935)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[24152:24159:0118/165349.354821:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(935)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[24152:24159:0118/165349.500902:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(935)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[24152:24159:0118/165420.719773:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(935)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
../../sandbox/linux/seccomp-bpf-helpers/sigsys_handlers.cc:**CRASHING**:(tg)kill() failure
--2020-01-18 16:54:20--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 172.217.0.14, 2607:f8b0:4009:813::200e
Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|172.217.0.14|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... [26470:26470:0118/165420.982513:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(450)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: Failed to create shared context for virtualization.
200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘/dev/fd/4’

     0K 
 Crash dump id:  370e7f42caa16b57 
                              [25935:1:0118/165421.699794:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(124)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuChannelMsg_CreateCommandBuffer.
[24152:24159:0118/165433.404758:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(935)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[24152:24159:0118/165433.405308:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(935)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[24152:24159:0118/165433.407261:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(935)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
../../sandbox/linux/seccomp-bpf-helpers/sigsys_handlers.cc:**CRASHING**:(tg)kill() failure
--2020-01-18 16:54:48--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 172.217.0.14, 2607:f8b0:4009:813::200e
Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|172.217.0.14|:443... connected.
[24112:24132:0118/165448.649960:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(990)] The display compositor is frequently crashing. Goodbye.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... --2020-01-18 16:54:48--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 172.217.0.14, 2607:f8b0:4009:813::200e
Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|172.217.0.14|:443... connected.
200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘/dev/fd/4’


     0KCrash dump id:  4680739215b13a66 
                                         HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘/dev/fd/4’

Crash dump id: 3c5b1d4ecc21b96a

     0K                           --2020-01-18 16:54:49--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 172.217.0.14, 2607:f8b0:4009:813::200e
Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|172.217.0.14|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘/dev/fd/4’


     0KCrash dump id:  29048ddcc54988c9 
                                   Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

Comment: Posting the output when you start the browser from a terminal would be more meaningful than your hardware. Those browsers are all based on Chrome/Chromium, so there might be a common component missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer, but not really a solution. The forums [here](https://forum.eset.com/topic/21896-chrome-79-always-starts-a-core-dump-and-crashes/) explained it well. It seems the antivirus I'm using is responsible for the crash. I can confirm that stopping the AV has allowed me to use all the web browsers without issue. In case anyone else has a similar problem I hope this will help you.

```
 Hi, I got into the same issue with Google Chrome 79 and Eset for Linux 4.0.93.0

Starting Chrome with --no-sandbox inline option fixes the issue. You get a warning by Chrome that disabling sandboxing may reduce stability and security, so this is not a permanent solution.

So the issue seems related to some incompatibility/conflict between Chrome sandboxing and Eset antivirus.
```